# Getting the error 'Timeouts are not supported on this stream' on the server

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, stream, filestream

When I saved a file I'm getting an error like this pic also I'm getting this error on the server. I have no problem on my local. Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

My save code is below;

```cs
public async Task<string> Upload(Stream stream, string filePath)
{
    filePath = PrepareServerPath(filePath);

    await CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(filePath);

    var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Flush();
    fileStream.Close();

    await Task.FromResult(true);
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: How are you saving ? Please add the code relevant for your question.

Comment: One tip from my side, please add Async sufix to CeateDirectoryIfNotExists. Same for Upload.

Comment: I added but it did not work. I'm getting same error.